# Magento 2: Change UI template

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, xml

For the checkout, I would like to use a different UI template to that which is used on the cart. Currently, they both use the same UI template: `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>`

`checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
...
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <!--Step configuration components-->
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                ...
```

`checkout_index_index.xml`

```
...
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            ...
```

As you can see, both are using the template `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>`. I would like to change this template on the checkout to be something like: `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field-checkout-only</item>`, as I would like to add some more attributes to the fields when on checkout.

I've tried to do this by creating `app/design/frontend/mitch/my_theme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/field-checkout-only.html` – this didn't work.

I then tried to change the `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>` to `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui::ui/form/field</item>`, but this still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For custom theme remove `web` folder

Change

```
app/design/frontend/mitch/my_theme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/field-checkout-only.html
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/mitch/my_theme/Magento_Ui/templates/form/field-checkout-only.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Mitch7663 did you check with default file it is working or not?

Comment: I worked out Magento have also specified the template in the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger` class... 

                   ` 'config' => [
                    'customScope' => $dataScopePrefix,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],`
Which isn't helpful :-(